# How to find non match records using three tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

I been struggling to create the following query.
I was provided with a spreadsheet that contains 2k `ID`s. I need to find out if those `ID` have records in two different tables. Each `ID` can have multiple records depending what group they belong to.

Example:

Table `masterIDS`(I imported the data into a temporary table), Table `IDS`, Table `AuditGroup`

**masterIDS**

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

**IDS**

| ID | location |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 12 |

**AuditGroup**

| name | location |
| --- | --- |
| X | 10 |
| Y | 11 |

What I need to do is:

Find all the IDs from `masterIDS` table in `IDS` table and if they are found they location from the `IDS` table needs to be the same in `AuditGroup` table. The `IDS` cant be null.
So for example, let say we use `ID=1` from `masterIDS` table and we look for it on `IDS` table and its found with a `location=10`, then we need to use that `location=10` to look for it on the `AuditGroup` table so `location=location` (the audit table doesn't have an `ID`). That location `10` can have many names so we might find on the `AuditGroup` table 5 `locations=10` but `name=a,b,c,d,f`...

The temporary tables masterIDs contains already all the IDS i need to query from. I believe i have done the above but how can I do  the non matches, for example i have ID=2 from mastersIDS i go look it up on IDS table i found it with location=12 but that is not in the AuditGroup table.

I have tried doing two joins, not in, not exists but i can figure it out

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should achieve what you're after, it returns a table of IDs and location which do not exist in the AuditGroup table.

```sql
-- Create MasterIDs and insert test data
CREATE TABLE #MasterIDs ([ID] INT)
INSERT INTO #MasterIDs VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO #MasterIDs VALUES (2)

-- Create IDs and insert test data
CREATE TABLE #IDs ([ID] INT, [location] INT)
INSERT INTO #IDs VALUES (1, 10)
INSERT INTO #IDs VALUES (2, 12)

-- Create AuditGroup and insert test data
CREATE TABLE #AuditGroup ([name] CHAR(1), [location] INT)
INSERT INTO #AuditGroup VALUES ('X', 10)
INSERT INTO #AuditGroup VALUES ('Y', 10)


SELECT mid.*, id.[location]
FROM #MasterIDs mid
LEFT JOIN #IDs id
ON mid.ID = id.ID
WHERE id.[location] NOT IN (SELECT [location] FROM #AuditGroup)


DROP TABLE #MasterIDs
DROP TABLE #IDs
DROP TABLE #AuditGroup
```